# Joomla External Link -

Tags: joomla

I am using the external link type menu items within Joomla - the reason is I need to link direct to an anchor on another page from the menu.

I have around 10-15 links, all work as expected except 2.

in my external URL box I have something like this:
"index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=10&Itemid=207#SystemIntegration"

- id - is the article id
- Itemid - is the menu item I want to be active
- hashtag - is my anchor link

PROBLEM:
On the 2 that are not working it seems to go to url with this "http://www.website.com/component/content/?Itemid=207#SystemIntegration" instead of "http://www.website.com/services/digital-solutions/SystemIntegration#SystemIntegration" as expected

has anyone else had this issue? I have a feeling its connected to the SEF urls being on.

Joomla 3.5.0 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing I tried worked reliably - so I got round it by making each item go to the single article, then using a spare field to store the name of anchor. Then within some custom JS code I checked if the field was set and automatically scrolled the page to it if it was - works better than the joomla standard anyway and is more reliable

Answer (score 0):

> Step1. Create a Hidden Menu from Joomla admin==>Menus==>Manage==>add
>   new menu
>
> Step2. Select a Hidden Menu ==> add a new menu item==>Menu Item 
>   Type==>Article==>single article==>your article id==>save
>
> Step3. Site load this url(take copy)
>
> Step4. Create a new menu from external url Pate the previous url
>   (include #)